# App Update Notification from Play Store After Once Ignored

Tags: react-native, google-play

I published my recent react native app apk to the play store.

Some users may have neglected the app update notification from play store and still using the previous one unknowingly. How to remind them to update it?

Comment: u can set up remote push notification

Comment: u can also try codepush for silent updates

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @riwu, a push notification is a great way to inform your user to update the app. It would be more interactive if you could put an alert in the app saying something like "Newer version of this app is available, Please update for better services" when the user receives a push notification .

You can also restrict the user if he isn't using the latest version app, and you don't want the previous version to be used. (A mandatory update)